# Passing an optional Enum to a function in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, enums, optional-parameters, enumerable

I am trying to pass an optional Enum to a function but can't get the syntax right. I am trying the following:

```
Public Function MyFunction(ByVal TestCode As String, Optional ByVal Columns As [Enum] = MyEnumName.EnumVariable) As Boolean
```

Also tried:

```
Public Function MyFunction(ByVal TestCode As String, Optional ByVal Columns As [Enum] = MyEnumName) As Boolean
```

And get the error message

"Conversion from "MyEnumName" to "System.Enum" cannot occur in a constant expression"

Is it possible to have optional Enums or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to pass an actual _enum type_ to the function, or the _value of an enum_?

Comment: I think you need to use '[Enum].MyEnumName' instead of 'MyEnumName'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with `Enum`s, you have to specify as type the given name rather than `[Enum]`. Sample code:

```
Public Enum MyEnumName
    val1
    val2
End Enum

Public Function MyFunction(ByVal TestCode As String, Optional ByVal Columns As MyEnumName = MyEnumName.val1) As Boolean

End Function
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @varocarbas